# Is there something like MaxProcessorUsed?

Tags: functions, gui-construction, performance-tuning

For standard procedures it is easy to test if the implementation is better or worse than other by using `Timing` etc.

It does not help us with creating `Dynamic` interfaces/visualisations. Sometimes it is obvious that one way is *more laggy*, but not always and it is not so precise method too.

**So my question is**: is there something like `MaxProcessorUsed` analogical to `MaxMemoryUsed`, so I could start it, play with the notebook, end it and get the result in terms of `%` for example.

---

I have not found anything so I'm looking forward seeing your ideas. :) This seems to be a useful tool for GUI creators.

Moreover, I've failed looking for anything to get information about current processor/cores state via *Mathematica* functions.

---

Also, I'm aware that the performance is not so easy to measure. We have to take under consideration GPU usage, existance of multi core vs. single vs. multi thread etc. But let's focus on basic case now.

Comment: It is normal the OSX system monitor.

Comment: @halirutan I thought so :/ thanks.